# How to dynamically un-collapse a Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have multiple versions of my page where the number of items in the `navbar` varies widely. The exact number of items is determined on the server.

In some cases, where the navbar only has 1 or 2 items, I want to un-collapse it -- I want to see all the items on the navbar (and not in the dropdown). Can this be done dynamically with Javascript? Or perhaps this can be done on the server when creating the HTML?

I'm aware that I can create a static CSS with http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ to control the collapse trigger width. But having 2 versions of Bootstrap CSS (one for large-screen collapse and one for small-screen collapse) and then trying to switch between doesn't seem very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Javascript jQuery sequence how to change from a **collapsible** Bootstrap 3 `navbar` to a **non-collapsible** `navbar`:

```
// Grab the height of the navbar
var navbarHeight = $('.navbar-header').height();
// Remove the navbar-toggle button
$('.navbar-toggle').remove();
// Move the collapsed section into the navbar-header
$('.collapse').appendTo('.navbar-header');
// Display all the collapsed items inline (assumes all the items are list items)
$('.collapse, .collapse ul, .collapse li').css('display', 'inline-block');
// Remove collapse class
$('.collapse').removeClass('collapse');
// Remove navbar-nav class (optional)
$('.navbar-nav').removeClass('navbar-nav');
// Hard-set the height of the navbar (optional)
$('.navbar-header').height(navbarHeight);
```

Note that the above sequence has only been tested with a few types of navbar elements. It may require additional steps for your navbar.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on the server when creating HTML. Once you get the exact number of items in the name bar, compare this value with a cutoff value (the maximum number of items in `navbar` ).
If the number of items is more then use navbar-collapse (may be displaying **more** ).

Answer (score 0):

You can add some jQuery that will count the number of list items in the div class="navbar-collapse collapse", and if the count returns a number smaller than 3, use .removeClass to remove the "collapse" class.

Something like this should work:

`if($('.navbar-collapse li').size() < 3) {
    $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass("collapse");
}`

Correction: .size is deprecated; use .length instead

Comment: I added a clarification to the question -- I'd like to see these items on the navbar, and not in the dropdown below it.